# MYSQL Create Index on one table, slows or locks performance on 2nd table

Tags: mysql

We update our website everyday by creating a new table.  When it's built and the indexes are created, we rename the old and new tables to swap them over.

**The sequence is as follows**

```
1. Create table (MyIsam)
2. Upload data
3. Create indexes
4. Rename current table to "data_old"
5. Rename new table to "data"
```

The problem we have is at stage 3, when the indexes are created on the "new" table.  The read performance of the old table suffers so much that the webserver balancer thinks there is a fault and starts showing "the website is busy"

8 indexes get created, 6 BTREE and 2 FULLTEXT.  When complete the data length of the table is 1.5Gb and the index length is 138Mb.

```
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 309Mb
key_buffer_size = 557Mb
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 60Gb
```

Overall we suffer around 15 mins of "downtime" while these index are created.

**Options**

Is there anyway to "multi thread" the operation so the action of creating indexes on the new table does not effect the read (select) performance on the original table?

Is it possible to tweak the mysql settings to reduce the amount of time it takes to create the indexes?

We currently perform the update in the early hours when not many users are online, but we often need to update during the day and want to avoid the downtime we currently get.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Why are you generating all data all over again? Why not just insert new data and delete old?

Comment: We update and insert new records into the database during the day as prices / stock change. We normally only recreate the database once a day from scratch.  It's done this way to remove index fragmentation issues and to ensure all "old stock" is flushed